# Printing content of XML in Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I am trying to print some basic logs in Perl but I get stuck on a very simple issue: I cannot print the contents of XML tags.

```
my $twig=XML::Twig->new(pretty_print => "nice");
$twig->parse($xml);
my $root = $twig->root;

my @desc=$root->descendants_or_self('node');
my $nrofdesc=@desc;

my $sentence = $root->descendants('sentence')->print;
my $sentenceid = $root->{att}->{id};

if ($nrofdesc > $maxdescendants) {
  print "$sentence\t$nrofdesc\t$sentenceid\n";
}
```

I tried tthe code above but I receive the error

> Can't call method "print" without a package or object reference at
>   file.pl line 35,  line 15.

Which is this line:

```
my $sentence = $root->descendants('sentence')->print;
```

I also tried `text` as is often proposed, but I get the same error. What am I missing here?

Comment: According to the perldoc `descendants` will give you a list, not an object. Probably you need to go through the list printing the indiviual 'twigs'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not jQuery ;--( You have to iterate through the list of descendants.

Plus you can't use `print` to collect data in a variable, you use `print` to... print! Use `sprint` instead:

```
$sentence= join '', map { $_->sprint } $root->descendants('sentence');
```

If what you want is the text of the elements, and the contents of all `sentence` elements is pure text, you could also use `$sentence= $root->findvalue( '//sentence')`

Also, use `$root->att( 'id')`, or `$root->id` since `$root->{att}->{id}` is not part of the official API, and could potentially change in the future.

Comment: But I know a priori that there will only be one `sentence` element per root. So why can't I just access that one item from a list? But you are right that I should use sprint I guess, I'll look into it. EDIT; no, I really needed `text`.

Comment: if you know there is only 1 sentence, or if you are only interested in the first one, then use either `$root->first_descendant( 'sentence')` or even `$twig->first_elt( 'sentence')`

Comment: Cool! (I deleted my answer so I can accept yours.) Question: when trying to use `first_elt` on `$root`  I get *Can't locate object method "first_elt" via package "XML::Twig::Elt"*. But when using it on twig it works. How's that?

Comment: sorry, I realized I made a mistake and edited my comment... after you read it apparently. The method on an element (`XML::Twig::Elt`) is `first_descendant`, not `first_elt`.